# WordPress Ajax code is not Working

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am developing a WordPress plugin to do shortcode and view PowerBI reports. I have all data in the json file. I have tested the file and the function code. There is no issues with the WordPress codes. There is something wrong in the following AJAX, showing following error in console.

```
POST: http://localhost/xxx/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 418ms]
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){         
    jQuery('.subjectdiv').on('click', 'a.acaret', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var rml_post_id = jQuery(this).attr( 'mydata' );    

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : mypowerbi_ajax.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'powerbi_manager_ajax',
                _ajax_nonce: mypowerbi_ajax.check_nonce,
                post_id : rml_post_id
            },
            success : function( response ) {
              jQuery('.powerbitabwindow').html(response);
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

Here is the function and its code

```
function fn_powerbi_manager($atts) {
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'), __FILE__);
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapscript', plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'), __FILE__);
  wp_enqueue_style('powerbistyle', plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/assets/css/style.css'), __FILE__);
  wp_enqueue_script('jqueryscript', plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/assets/js/jquery.min-v3.5.1.js'), __FILE__);
  wp_enqueue_script('powerbiscript', plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/assets/js/scripts.js'), __FILE__);

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrapstyle');
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrapscript');
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'powerbistyle');
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jqueryscript');
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'powerbiscript');
  
  wp_register_script( 'myajax-script', plugins_url( 'assets/js/ajaxcall.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'myajax-script' );
  wp_localize_script( 'myajax-script', 'mypowerbi_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'check_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('powerbi_manager_nonce') ));

   require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__).'templates/frontend-page.php';
}
function my_powerbi_manager_ajax() 
{
    check_ajax_referer( 'powerbi_manager_nonce' );
     $rml_post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
     $json = file_get_contents(plugins_url('/powerbi_manager/json/powerbimanager.json'));
     $decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);
     $shortcodedata = array();
     foreach ($decoded_json as $rkey => $jsondata){
       if ($jsondata['visualidentifier'] == $rml_post_id){

           $shortcodedata[] = $jsondata['shortcode'];
       } 
    }
     echo do_shortcode($shortcodedata[0]);
}

if (function_exists('my_powerbi_manager_ajax'))
{
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_powerbi_manager_ajax', 'my_powerbi_manager_ajax' ); 
}
add_shortcode('powerbi-manager', 'fn_powerbi_manager');
```

Can anyone please find the error or give me suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I have logged out from the WordPress. I have added this code, now it is working,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_powerbi_manager_ajax', 'my_powerbi_manager_ajax' );
```